# What is the NFL record for most receivers with a catch in a single game on one team?

Tags: trivia, nfl, records

The Saints are up to [ten unique receivers](http://www.nfl.com/gamecenter/2014112400/2014/REG12/ravens@saints#tab=analyze) with at least one catch in tonight's game against the Ravens, and I can find a reference to the Packers having [a franchise record of 12](http://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2011/10/09/rodgers-spreads-the-ball-around-as-packers-score-25-straight/) that's been reached multiple times - but what's the overall record for most receivers with a catch in a single game on the one team?

Comment: I have scoured the internet and cannot find any mention of what the record is.  I have found a couple occasions in the preseason where 15 players caught passes (of course in the preseason the rosters are bigger).  For the regular season though, I think 12 is probably the record, but I have no way of proving it.

Comment: Having gone through the 242 games with 34+ passes completed by a QB, I'm drawing the line at going through the next 2135 games with 26 (Rodgers' total) to 33 passes completed.  In that first range I did find [one more 12 reception game](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/196909280min.htm).

Comment: Are you going through the games manually or using some sort of script?

Comment: Manually.  If I could get to box scores via an SQL query, I could probably extract the info but that doesn't seem available anywhere either.

Comment: The most this year was Brees and Alex Smith tied at 11. Bree did it twice and did it [week 17 vs TB](http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554443). I remember this mentioned during the game. I would guess you could go to Elias or pro-football-refernce to try to figure out the all time high. Not sure this is sortable other than going through every box score. But obviously Elias has a way to filter this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be 12:

> The Saints became just the third team in the past 30 years to have 12 different players catch a pass, according to the Elias Sports Bureau data.

from [ESPN](https://www.espn.com/nfl/story/_/id/30282885/with-deep-talented-receiving-corps-back-play-drew-brees-new-orleans-saints-stay-hot)